# Android GridView with Picasso display image wrongly

Tags: java, android, listview, gridview, adapter

I have a gridview that display images only.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_user_image_adapter, null);
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            viewHolder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            viewHolder.imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(this.width, this.width));
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Log.i("XXX", "" + this.data.size());

        if (i == this.data.size() - 1)) {
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_add_photo);
        } else if (this.data.get(i) != null && !this.data.get(i).equals("")) {
**// Option 1**
//            Picasso.with(this.context)
//                    .load(this.data.get(i))
//                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.default_image_load_fail_user)
//                    .resize(400, 400)
//                    .centerCrop()
//                    .into(viewHolder.imageView);

**// option 2**
//            viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.default_man);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }
```

When I use Picasso, the first image and the second image are the same!
But when using option2, The two images are displayed diffferently

Why?//

Comment: Check if `this.data.get(i)` returns same image for position 0 and 1.

Comment: @ Pankaj Kumar I am sure that they are not the same

Comment: no, not yet another "if without else" in getView ... there are bazillion questions about this just use search with "wrong images/data in xxxxxView" where xxxx is Grid, List ... all is becuase not understanding view recycling ...  please watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) with understanding (yes, it is about ListView but both those classes are AbsListView ... so most of stuff apply to both classes)

Comment: viewHolder.imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(this.width, this.width));
 try to remove this line

Comment: @selvin your past answer  solved my problems... Thank you